# glm::dot() doesn't return float/double value?

Tags: c++, glm-math

I am trying to use `glm::dot` to calculate the dot product of two `glm::dvec3`

However, my compiler returns this error when I try to do this

```
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    glm::dvec3 a = glm::dvec3(1f, 2f, 3f);
    glm::dvec3 b = glm::dvec3(4f, 5f, 6f);
    float weight = glm::dot(a, b)
}
```

ERROR: `Type 'double' and 'glm::dvec3' are not compatible` in the last line when I assign weight to the result of glm::dot

I am using (clion, cygwin, gcc) and glm 0.9.8 and c++ 11

**EDIT:** Add more detailed error location and code context

Comment: Edit in a [mcve].  VS2015 compiles the snippet fine if I convert the `float` arguments to the `dvec3()` ctors to `double` literals.  When you get that MCVE spun up edit in the full compiler error line (which should list a line number and possibly location within a line).

Comment: Thanks, I have made some edits. Even when I substituted 1f with double literal 1.0 and so on, I still have this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is a better solution, but this is working for me

```
glm::vec3 a;
glm::vec3 b;
glm::dot<3, float, glm::qualifier::highp>(a, b);
```

Since GLM has two methods dot

```
template<typename T>
GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER T dot(T x, T y)
{
    GLM_STATIC_ASSERT(std::numeric_limits<T>::is_iec559, "'dot' accepts only floating-point inputs");
    return x * y;
}
template<length_t L, typename T, qualifier Q>
GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER T dot(vec<L, T, Q> const& x, vec<L, T, Q> const& y)
{
    GLM_STATIC_ASSERT(std::numeric_limits<T>::is_iec559, "'dot' accepts only floating-point inputs");
    return detail::compute_dot<vec<L, T, Q>, T, detail::is_aligned<Q>::value>::call(x, y);
}
```

The compiler is assuming that T is vec3 and for that reason is using the first method

Take a look to this post:

[Templates C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/)

> In this specific case where the generic type T is used as a parameter
>   for GetMax the compiler can find out automatically which data type has
>   to instantiate without having to explicitly specify it within angle
>   brackets (like we have done before specifying  and ). So we
>   could have written instead: int i,j; GetMax (i,j);

Hope this helps